# Publish and Presentation Program of FSG Report Set completes with Status: Warning

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oraclereports, oracle-ebs

I've got the following situation:

a user of Oracle Financials (12.1.3) runs an FSG report set; Financial Statement Generator part completes normally, but the Publish and Presentation Program completes with warning.

The user ran the same FSG report set multpile times on the same day, with intervals of between 5 to 30 minutes and some of the request completed successfully, some other not. It seems to be random - I checked parameters used for all 22 reports and did not find any pattern whatsoever.

Of the total number of 22 reports run, 12 completed successfully.

I reviewed the log files of the ones with warning and compare to the ones completed successfully.

The warning always coincides with no value set for two parameters:

"...
processing parameters, NVT name MENU_TYPE val  END PARAM
processing parameters, NVT name MENU_ID val  END PARAM
..."

Then the final message reads:

"...
Param size? 31 Is In set? falsein set - , NVT name = PUBLISH_SET_ID, val =  END PARAMJan 8, 2015 12:37:08 PM oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigFactoryfindOrCreateADFConfig
INFO: oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigFactory No META-INF/adf-config.xml found
Publishing completed successfully  with document id: -1
Published doc Id: -1Publishing did not complete successfully, unable to insert data into database
..."

When compared to the log file of the program completed successfully, I found the above lines showing:

"...
processing parameters, NVT name MENU_TYPE val Document END PARAM
processing parameters, NVT name MENU_ID val 8473 END PARAM
...
in set - , NVT name = PUBLISH_SET_ID, val =  END PARAM
Param size? 31 Is In set? falsein set - , NVT name = PUBLISH_SET_ID, val =  END PARAMJan 8, 2015 12:43:43 PM oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigFactoryfindOrCreateADFConfig
INFO: oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigFactory No META-INF/adf-config.xml found
Publishing completed successfully  with document id: 8473
Request Id 13888123 submitted to generate FO for the document 8473
Published doc Id: 8473About to create menu with these details:
...
"
Never experienced this problem before.

There were no patches applied or maintenance programs run that could affect FSG reports as far I know.

I wonder if anyone experienced this issue and would be able to provide me with some hints on how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dead-on in your assumption that it follows the lack of value-set in the parameters. I recommend reading [MOS Doc ID 1385357.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1385357.1).

You must set this content set then republish the FSG.

---

Final answer to this problem:

- Content Set was OK.
- User used an obsolete template, which resulted in the report completing with warning.
- Problem stopped occuring when the right template was used.

Comment: Thanks, but this article relates to a different problem. I do not get any error, in particular this one "Error in content set COC FUND CC CHILD PAGE EXPAND override 1.
No segments values for segment SEGMENT1 in range ZOP to ZOP.". There is nothing wrong with the content set for my FSG report. The problem is that the same report X using parameters Z one time finishes successfully and another time finishes with warning caused by no values for the indicated parameters... But no parameters have been changed.

Comment: Logic would suggest that if you run two requests on a set of data using the same set of parameters and assuming that the data set used has not been changed, you should get the same output. This is not the case with my report.

Comment: Can you see anything in the OPP log?

Comment: Ha, I haven't checked that! Will do on Monday. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It's possible that you might be topping out the memory and/or using an obsolete template. Is this reproducible or only in prod?

Comment: It's in prod only. I could not replicate this warning, it affected only one user. Checked OPP: no OPP log files available even for reports completed successfully. That's weird. No out of memory errors although got ORA-04021 and ORA-06512: at "APPS.FND_CP_OPP_IPC" on several occassions. Will keep looking into this. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: NP OPP troubleshooting his half our jobs. So the `ORA-06512` error means it can't find the OPP at all. See [1059712.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1059712.1) for details and an action plan on that.

Comment: So when I proxied on to user's PC to observe how user runs this report, it turned out that the user actually used an obsolete template, a possibility that you mentioned in one of your comments. When I applied the right template everything was fine... Never trust users! ;-) I am going to edit your answer just to make it more transparent, if you don't mind.